# Bootstrap 5 navbar single items differently aligned

Tags: html, css, django

I can't get this button on this navbar to be aligned right.

I want **"Anhänger"**, **"Camping"** and **"Kontakt"** centered and only the button **"Anfahrt"** on the right. Now, first I got really confused with all the different bootstrap versions and the different commands, and my actual progress is the second toolbar here:

https://www.codeply.com/p/DjlnoDXYCt

As you can see, I got the "Anfahrt" Button to be aligned right through "ms-auto", but then "justify-content-end" doesn't work!

Can someone help me? It seems like such an easy problem, but I cannot get my head around it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this. It will be shown responsive here. You can add in your code and check

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-MrcW6ZMFYlzcLA8Nl+NtUVF0sA7MsXsP1UyJoMp4YLEuNSfAP+JcXn/tWtIaxVXM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarText" aria-controls="navbarText" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarText">
      <ul class="navbar-nav me-auto mb-2 mb-lg-0">
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#">Anhänger</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Camping</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Kontakt</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <ul class="navbar-nav me-auto mb-2 mb-lg-0">
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#">Anhänger</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Camping</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Kontakt</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <button class="btn btn-info">
        Anfahrt
      </button>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

check this out:

```
<nav class="nav navbar bg-light">
  <div class="d-flex mx-auto">
    <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" aria-current="page" href="#">Anhänger</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Camping</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#" id="kontakt">Kontakt</a>
      </li>
      </div>
    <div class="d-flex">
        <li class="nav-item px-2">
          <a class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" href="#" role="button">Anfahrt</a>
        </li>
    </div>
</nav>
```